# lightning:checkboxGroup - set checkbox indeterminate = true

Tags: javascript, lightning, locker-service, inputcheckboxes

I'm using lightning:checkboxGroup and I'm trying to set the state one of the individual checkboxes as indeterminate. I tried the following JS:

```
component.find("my-chbxgroup").getElement().querySelector("input[value=val1]").indeterminate = true;
```

But Locker Service won't let me access the DOM of lightning:checkboxGroup.

Is there any way I could accomplish it without disabling Locker Service?

Comment: A minimal set of code to replicate the issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `<lightning:input type="checkbox" ... />` then I think you are stuck for now as that does not expose an attribute that can set the underlying DOM `indeterminate` property that then drives the [SLDS styling](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/).

You will have to experiment. One solution might be to create your own checkbox Lightning Component that does expose an `indeterminate` property. Be sure to apply the SLDS classes. (This would be a bit cleaner than using raw HTML.)